# Tile System, Cant place 'tower' on certain cell

Tags: xna

I've got a tile system in place, and have a few images loading into that, I have it coded so that if the cell is a 'path' then you can't place down a tower, but i was wandering how i would go about making it so that i couldnt place a tower down on more than one texture, or if it would be easier to say that it can only be placed onto a certain texture, rather than listing textures that it cant be put down on?

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier in the long run to specify only the textures that a tower can be placed on, as this way, when you add another type of tile, you don't need to add it to the black-list.

A white-list allows greater extensibility, and easier maintenance.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i thought. Do you know how i would go about doing this?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's almost impossible to give you an accurate implementation of this, as there is no guarantee it would be compatible.